# 2 factor authentication handling in selenium webdriver with python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am logging to a website with valid credentials, but if my network changes or even device gets changed (within same network); it redirects to Authentication page where I have to put the access code, which I received via email. I want to skip this authentication page and navigate to other pages to continue my process.

Expected result - Home page of the site
Actual result - Secure Access Code page

Comment: I guess that authentification doesnt let you continue doing what previouse u were doing. Your expected result seems that you just want to do current = drive.current_url every x seconds and then driver.get(current) .. I eould recommand you to add some more info on what you want to achieve if this is not the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

When you initialise your driver you can  configure the browser to load your chrome profile, that is if your using chrome. This may allow you to bypass the authentication page if you have had a previous login with this profile. Not sure if this will work but it worth a shot.